# Local admininstrator account can't change uac settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

I have 2  accounts on my computer, both of them are local administrators. However, for one of them. UAC keeps popping up. I tried go to change the settings and it says I must be a local administrator.

What does this mean? I have already verified this account is already in the administrators localgroup.

I have also tried modifying the UAC setting from a admin command prompt.

Here is where it gets weird: Instead of showing this account's settings, it instead shows the setting I have the other account on. I took a screenshot of the 2 UAC windows side by side. The one on the left being the one run from admin command prompt. The one the right is when I normally access UAC from the start bar and tried to change the setting to what it is on the other account.

How can I fix this so I can change UAC for this account? OR How can I get this machine to recognize this account is a local administrator with regards to UAC?

Here are some screenshots.
[image]

accounts
[image]

Here are the HKLM registry settings for UAC
[image]

Comment: Standard or Pro version of Windows?

Comment: msinfo32.exe says Home edition, so I am assuming standard.

Comment: Hmmm, I think what I want is this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232762.aspx

Comment: Hmm i can't find UAC reg settings for each individual user. If I had that, I could export them from my other account and import them into this one.  But  I only found those UAC reg settings in HKLM. Are they stored somewhere else for users?

Comment: No, UAC settings always apply to the entire machine. I'm not certain this setting is your problem...(though I don't have a better idea).

Comment: I guess the question then becomes, why is this account getting treated as a user with regards to UAC when it is actually a local administrator?